# Recycle bin refresh

Tags: windows, visual-c++, windows-shell

If I delete the contents of the Recycler folder manually(c++) how can I notify the shell of the file deletion ? So that the Empty recycle bin icon appears ?
**Edit** I use DeleteFile() to delete the files.

```
 typedef int (CALLBACK*  UpdateRecycleBinIcon)(void);
 int  x = 0;
HINSTANCE dllHandle = NULL;
dllHandle = LoadLibrary(_T("shell32.dll"));
 UpdateRecycleBinIcon update = NULL;
 if(dllHandle != NULL) {
     update = (UpdateRecycleBinIcon)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon");
     if(update != NULL)

           x = update();
        printf("%d\n",x);
 }
```

it prints 1.

Comment: Which function do you use to empty recycle bin, SHEmptyRecycleBin ?

Comment: I use the plain DeleteFile function

Comment: Why to empty entire recycle bin? There might be 100s of (deleted) files in Bin, may be from different folder/driver/user. And you, the smart-guy, willing to empty entire recycle bin just for your ONE file?

Comment: I don't delete one file and actually I don't solely rely on DeleteFile, I want to SHRED the contents of Recycle Bin. I'm sure it makes sense now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you must call [SHChangeNotify](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

Edited example:

```
// Get an IDList for the recycle bin.
LPITEMIDLIST a_pstIDList = NULL;
SHGetSpecialFolderLocation( NULL, CSIDL_BITBUCKET, &a_pstIDList );
// Get icon index in the system image list.
SHFILEINFO sfi = {0};
SHGetFileInfo((LPCSTR)a_pstIDList, 0, &sfi, sizeof(SHFILEINFO), SHGFI_PIDL | SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX);

SHChangeNotify(SHCNE_UPDATEIMAGE, SHCNF_DWORD, 0, sfi.iIcon);
```

Comment: Have you tested it ? it doesn't work for me and it also asks me for casting sfi.iIcon to LPCVOID, so I do the cast and it doesn't work.

Comment: I not test yet. I work in similar objective many years ago. I dont exactly remember solutipn. But why dont use SHEmptyRecycleBin as pointed Jonathan ?

Comment: Would there be any reason for which this would not work? Because it works in the GUI app after I initialize the com and stuff... but it does not work immediately  in a simple console app. Is there any further preparations that I need to do?

Answer (score 2):

You could try calling SHEmptyRecycleBin() once you've deleted the files yourself, that might cause the shell to update.

Comment: Well deleting files manually from the recycle bin using DeleteFile() isn't really the right way either :)

Comment: Good point there. But just let's say I want to do my on  SHEmptyRecycleBin()

Answer (score 1):

Is also possible refresh Recycle Bin icon using undocumented shell32.dll function `SHUpdateRecycleBinIcon`. See this VB6 example:
[How can I empty My recycle Bin?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vblanguage/thread/b3157375-2487-4555-b259-7fe4a24e4855/)

Comment: I hope you're not joking cause I haven't found the function. Where to find and how to include it?

Comment: It annoys the crap out of me that I have to settle down for this workaround with  SHEmptyRecycleBin() , it's just not the right way to do it!

Comment: I wrote you. Is undocumented function. I think, is exported as ordinal 346 in Windows XP.

Comment: Can I include it using this : #pragma comment(lib, "shell32.lib") ?

Comment: OK, if you want use undocumented function, you must know ordinal number (or name) and parameters. Then use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress.

Comment: Hei, I've edited my post with the code, but it still doesn't work, am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Function returns S_FALSE, is hard to answer because is undocumented.